# VBA - Slow process of picking value from another file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pick values from another workbook. The idea is : when another division wants my division to perform a task, they just have to update their own sheet and periodically, my workbook will pick the right information based on certain conditions.

I've tried running my code with breaks and with the udpating of the screen activated, and it turns out that the picking of the values and the writing in my workbook is incredibly slow (up to 15-20 seconds per task for 9 cells).

I don't really understand why, because I don't use any copy paste, and I tried using variables for my sheets... Any ideas to optimize my code ?

I use the following type of lines to pick the info for up to 9 cells.

```
For j = 1 To NombreTache Step 1
    Cells(bnglastrow + j, "F") = dviws.Cells(ListeTache(j), "P")  'This is done 9 times on several columns
Next j
```

Edit : I forgot to mention that ListeTache is an array, composed of the numbers of the rows where we can find tasks to be transfered.

Comment: Are there any calculations being run that take the values as an input?  And, if so, does performance improve if you set `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` at the start of the code, and `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end?

Comment: There is no calculation being done, as the code follows this process :
-it run through the source file, in a column where dates are stored
-if the date is the one of the current day (stored in a variable), we add the number of the line in the array
-Once this loop is done, we loop the array to pick the data based on the row

EDIT : I tried your method and it worked just fine ! Now it's almost immediate ! Thank you so much !

Comment: The calculations in question are any Excel formulae in the spreadsheet, not VBA code.  If the Calculation Mode is set to Automatic, it will attempt to recalculate the entire workbook in every iteration of the loop (i,e. if `NombreTache` is 9, then it will set a cell, then calculate the workbook, then set the second cell, recalculate the workbook, third cell, third recalculation, etc, until it reaches 9)